# CPU Load average rule for a minute

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

Thank you in advance for reading my question.

I'm using both Grafana and Prometheus to monitor systems.

```
avg(node_load1{instance="$node",job="$job"}) /  count(count(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="$node",job="$job"}) by (cpu)) * 100
```

The above query is used in **Grafana** to check Load average for 1 minute.

**Could you let me know how to write the query in Prometheus?**
I just copied it and pasted into Prometheus, but there was no result.

```
node_load1 / count by (instance, job) (node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}) * 100 >= 95
```

I also tried using the query above. However, the calculated CPU Load average was a little bit different from the origin query in Grafana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "$node" and "$job" are variables defined in the Grafana tool, they can't be used in Prometheus this way. We need to replace with the real value of them, for example:

```
avg(node_load1{instance="my_instance",job="my_job"}) /  count(count(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="my_instance",job="my_job"}) by (cpu)) * 100
```

Or simply, remove them:

```
avg(node_load1) / count(count(node_cpu_seconds_total) by (cpu)) * 100
```

Comment: Hi Marcelo, Thank you for the answer. I tried the second and the result was the only one. `{}   0.4573532222 `
I’d like to find a way to see each instance’s result which is counted by its cpu. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: If you want to have the percentage of Load by CPU of each instance, you have to use your second PromQL (node_load1 / count by (instance, job) (node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}) * 100). With the first PromQL, that you're using on Grafana, you'll not get the same result (it's wrong).